# if we could abort a committed transaction what would happen with durability

Tags: database-design

If we could abort a committed transaction, what would happen with durability?
Then durability would not be ensured, right?

Note: I mean **undoing** a committed transaction by **aborting**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you could "abort a committed transaction* then yes you lose **Durability**, and effectively can say you lose **Atomicity** and **Consistency** as defined by the [**ACID principals**](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGMCP_5.4.0/product-overview/acid.html) for a database system.

The reasoning being is other transactions could have subsequently occurred that relied on the outcome of the initial transaction, which you are now "aborting" / rolling back, without rolling back those subsequent changes.

In other words, other data in the database may have been generated off of the data result of the original transaction that was committed which you are now undoing, and that subsequent data will not be rolled back, therefore creating inconsistency within the database.

In order to try to restore **consistency** all subsequent changes to the database that resulted from that rolled back committed transaction would also need to be undone, and all other subsequent changes based on those transactions would need to be undone as well, etc, etc. There could be a long list of child, grandchild, great-grandchild, etc changes that all ultimately resulted from that initial single committed transaction that you're rolling back.

Comment: Thank you so much @J.D.  Sorry can you please how we would lose Atomicity  too?

Comment: @learn9909 No problem! If you take the example of **Atomicity** in the link on **ACID principals**, it states how if you debit one account in the banking system you have to credit the correlating appropriate account (so the account balances). But based on what I said in my answer with rolling back a single committed transaction, if you undid the debit transaction to one account in the example system, the added credit transaction would still persist in the correlating account and the two accounts would no longer balance correctly, breaking the **Atomicity**. Hopefully this make sense.

Comment: But in this example the debiting and adding the credit both are in ONE transaction not in two different transaction. Can you please explain?

Comment: @learn9909 Actually that might be my mistake then, I assumed the example meant two separate transactions. In that case, it may not affect **Atomicity** (it's been a while since I brushed up on those principal definitions), but mainly **Consistency** is the principal being broken by your question, and I believe **Durability** can be argued as well.

Comment: I can definitely see scenarios where consistency would be compromised by aborting already committed transactions. I can also think of examples where it would not affect consistency at all. The DBMS can only enforce consistency in so far as constraints have been declared to it. It would be possible for the DBMS to refuse to roll back an already committed transaction if that action violated the declared constraints. Conceptually no different to it refusing to commit a new transaction that violated those constraints.

Comment: Atomicity encompasses all of the actions within a single transaction. Either they are all committed or they are all rolled back. In this putative example the same principle would say either all actions are retroactively rolled back or none can be retroactively rolled back. I think the concept of atomicity could be expanded to included this hypothetical.

Comment: On the second paragraph about "other transactions .. subsequently". This is true for current DBMS unless there are specific constraints in place to prevent it. Some such constraints are easily declared, foreign keys for example. Others are not and require assertions, which are not widely supported, or user code, which cannot be inserted into every single transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Durability was never a scientifically defined concept. It has always been contingent. Loosely, it is thought of as "once committed data will not be lost." There's an implied bit at the end, though: ".. not be lost *by mistake*."

The durability guarantee is about a client's actions on a data store no longer being volatile i.e. surviving a re-start of the system software or hardware. There was never any guarantee committed data would survive future requests from clients.

Say the client of your putative system inserted value "A" into the database, committed, and restarted the system. We would expect to see the value A when the system came back up because "insert A" is a valid instruction and the system guarantees durability. Now we insert B and commit. Now we roll back the transaction that inserted A and "commit", and restart the system. What values would we expect to see when it comes back up? The system was issued a legitimate instruction to undo the insert of A, and that instruction's effects were hardened to disk, so A should not be in the data. It seems to me this proposed system still offers durability guarantees that match the D in ACID. Setting aside referential integrity problems for now, this is no different (as far as durability specifically is concerned) to the schedule of commands insert a, commit, insert b, commit, delete a, commit.

By "contingent" I mean durability has only ever been as good as the hardware on which it runs, even for current mainstream commercial databases. All work done on any DB since the last backup was secured off-site is subject to unrecoverable loss. This may be due to fire, theft, encryption by hackers, incompetence or any number of other circumstances. What use is the durability guarantee then? The DBMS sent messages saying those transactions were committed, external actions (email etc.) may have been taken as a result. It matters not one jot; that data is lost forever.

This is why enterprises and cloud providers put so much effort into storage replication and geographic distribution of that storage.

Business continuity plans use two measures - recovery time objective (RTO) and recovery point objective (RPO). The latter states how much data, measured by time, a business is prepared to loose in the event of a disaster, and therefore how much protection that business should provide for that data. It is an explicit acknowledgement of the fact that durability is contingent on the severity of the event that occurs.